# Windows 10 Mobile: how can I see inside on my app folder?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I'm deploying my Windows 10 Mobile application on my device. I want to inspect the folder to be sure the application created folders and files.

How can I do that? I tried with the [webapp](http://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/post/How-to-deploy-an-Universal-Windows-Project-on-real-device-mobile) in the phone but I access only on the Documents folder.

I asked this here because in my Windows Phone with latest update (I active Windows Insider Programme then I think I have for sure the latest version of the OS) I can't explore app folders as you see on the following picture. If I click on the link *User files* nothing happened.

I have access only with network because if I try to open http://127.0.0.1:10443 nothing happened. Maybe it's only a problem on my device.

[image: File Explorer on my dekstop]

I tried to open *File explorer* directly on the Windows Phone but the result was exactly the same.

[image]

My Windows 10 Mobile version is 1607, OS Build 10.0.14915.1000

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I can reproduce your issue. Please check my updated answer. Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use **[App File Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#app-file-explorer)** to view and manipulate files stored by your sideloaded apps. This tool should be able to work no matter your application is deployed in Debug mode or Release mode. But please note that this is a **new tool** added to Device Portal in the **Anniversary Update** (AU).

For how to use this tool, please see [Using the App File Explorer to see your app data](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/) and also [Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile).

If your mobile's OS Version is earlier than Anniversary Update such as OS Build 10586, then you can use [IsolatedStorageExplorer (ISE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from Windows Phone 8.1 or some other open-source tools like [IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) and [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=273005).

**Update:**

Thanks for your feedback. I can reproduce your issue when I test with Windows 10 Mobile OS Build 10.0.14915.1000.
[image]

Here, to access with USB, the address should be **https://127.0.0.1:10443**. As it is said in [Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile#turn-on-device-discovery-and-pairing):

> USB: `http://127.0.0.1:10080`
>
> Use this address when the phone is connected to a PC via a USB connection. Both devices must have Windows 10, Version 1511 or later.

So when we connected via USB, we need use `http://127.0.0.1:10080` and if we enabled authentication, it will automatically redirect to `https://127.0.0.1:10443`.

After refreshing this page, I can see ***LocalAppData*** under ***User files***
[image]
However, there is nothing in ***LocalAppData***.
[image]
This seems to be an Insider Preview issue as App File Explorer works well in latest RTM OS version (Build 14393). For Insider Preview issues, please feel free to share feedbacks with Microsoft. You can report this issue with **Windows Feedback app**. Your feedback has made Windows better!

And as a workaround, you can try with the tools I've mentioned above or using [Device Portal core API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core#app-file-explorer) like following:

```
https://127.0.0.1:10443/api/filesystem/apps/files?knownfolderid=LocalAppData&packagefullname=3f828c97-6b7d-4068-8f9c-710df704c8ff_1.0.0.0_arm__9wkhgz7fyfewr
```

App File Explorer also built on top of these APIs. You can change `packagefullname` to see the app you are interested in. And you can use

```
GET /api/app/packagemanager/packages
```

to get associated details of installed packages.

For more info, please see [Device Portal core API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core).

Comment: When trying to open WhatsApp I get a {"Code" : -2147467259, "CodeText" : "Unspecified error\r\n", "Reason" : "File access is only allowed for developer packages", "Success" : false} via the API. Any clue?