# access windows 10 mobile root files and folders

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows 10 universal app that is running on a Windows 10 Mobile device. I noticed from the Windows 10 Mobile device, it does have a file explorer but it limits you to only see certain "Known Folders" such as music, documents, downloads, etc... and that is all.

Furthermore, when I plug the device into my development machine via USB, I can browse the device but again, only the Known Folders above.

In my app, I am writing to a log file and that log file is stored to LocalStorage, under a folder for my app name, for example:

```
 var dataPath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
```

I simply need to browse MY LOG FILE, that MY APP CREATES, in MY APP FOLDER. I read about a ton of, in my opinion hacks, to get access to this file/folder. For example, there are some third party applications that still mainly claim to target Windows Phone 8/8.1 but will still technically work for 10 such as:

Windows Phone Power Tools
Isolated storage spy
etc....

Then I also read articles on how to use a file in Pictures (or voice recording) and go to file properties to then gain access to the root or to create a root shortcut on the development machine and copy it to the mobile device, however, these are typically a year or more old and no longer work on my device (I suspect MS patched these hacks).

So, all that said, I would like to see a good way to access the root drive for development, or at least my app folder in the LocalFolder so I can access my files (such as logs or the sqlite db file). Maybe there is a way already but my google searches haven't turned anything up just yet.

Thanks!

Comment: It is a good thing that files are protected... so that as a user we can have confidence that an application would not have access to other application data. It also make maintenance and uninstallation easier as it allows to associate data with an application.

Comment: @Phil1970 yes, agree, that is a good thing. However, that isnt really my issue. My problem is, as the user/owner of the actual device, I have no way or no easy way to browse the root storage of my device. To see the data apps are putting on my device. I can understand this as a default for most users but even then, it would be nice if there was still a way or a setting to enable me to browse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075781/how-to-access-application-data-folder-in-windows-10-phone#comment69384644_41075781

Comment: Why the down vote on my question???

Comment: Again, fellow SO community members, to second my comment from 12/13, I received another down vote to my question today. I feel it is a legitimate question and does have some answers. That said, if we want the content on this site to improve, you can't just down vote, you need to also leave a comment. I literally have no idea why this question has received two down votes because of this. I am willing to learn and improve my questions and content but I am not getting the feedback. Just leaving a down vote does not teach me anything! So, why the down vote???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've known, we can use some third party tools like [IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) or [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to access Isolated Storage. Although they are designed for Windows Phone 8 & 8.1, but they can also be used for Windows 10 Mobile. With these two tools, we can access [LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder.aspx), [TemporaryFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder.aspx) and [RoamingFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder.aspx). For more info, see similar question: [Accessing storage of simulator/device while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036398/accessing-storage-of-simulator-device-while-debugging).

Besides these third party tools, there is also build-in support in Windows 10. We can use **[App File Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#app-file-explorer)** to view and manipulate files stored by your sideloaded apps. This is a new, cross-platform version of the [Isolated Storage Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx) from Windows Phone 8.1. This tool should be able to work no matter your application is deployed in Debug mode or Release mode. But please note that this is a **new tool** added to [Windows Device Portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal) in the **Anniversary Update**.

To use this feature, we must [enable Device discovery and Device Portal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile#turn-on-device-discovery-and-pairing). Then we can access application storage in web browser like following:
[image]

For more info, please see [Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile) and [Using the App File Explorer to see your app data](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/). Also the similar question: [Windows 10 Mobile: how can I see inside on my app folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276018/windows-10-mobile-how-can-i-see-inside-on-my-app-folder) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve few months back. I ended up doing two things:

1. I've implemented a 'Send Logs' button in settings that would upload logs to a ftp server. Actually it was a bit more than that, all installations of this app were managed by a central server and there was 'Get logs' button on the server side that would send request via push channel to the device to get the logs.
2. Got my hands on a Interop-unlocked device that I would use if the app was in a state that would make first option not possible.

Comment: I can look into these options. I still think it sucks. I understand what MS is trying to do to protect majority of the users but there should still be a way, maybe in settings, for a user to turn off this setting and still access the whole root of the device. Question, is there anything stopping me from simply storing my app data in the Known Folders area so it can be accessed easily, like Pictures and Downloads are?